# How to position these elements on the same row?

Tags: html, css

I have some GUI components that don't line up on the same row which I want them to:
[image]

I want them all on the same row. What must be done then?
My HTML is

```
<div id="rab" class="yta2   TB_nb fontS80">
    <div class="fl50" id="L-col">
    <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl25"><h3>Åberopade rabattgrundande ärenden</h3></div>
    <div class="fl40">Registrera: 
    <input type="radio" name="its" checked value="its">ITS
    <input type="radio" name="uppdrag" value="uppdrag">Uppdrag
    <input type="radio" name="pct" value="pct">PCT/Patentansökan
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="fl40">ITS inlämnad datum:
    <input type="text" size="10" name="pct_inlamningsdatum" 
id="pct_inlamningsdatum" value="">&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="15" alt="" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','depositionsdatum')"></a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="fl20">Nummer:</div>
    <div class="fl40"><input type="text" name="pct_nr"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="fl50" id="R-col">
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl95 hknot" style="height: 165px; overflow: auto;">

<table><tr><td><strong>Myndighet</strong></td><td><strong>Datum</strong></td><td><strong>Nummer</strong></td><td><strong>Utlämning</strong></td></tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
                color: #90002b; 
                font-size: 140%; 
                display: inline; 
                vertical-align: 3%; 
                margin-left: 1%;
                }

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}

.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}
.smallb{font-size: 85%;}
table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}
h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}



.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
        text-align: left;
}

.labb{F0F0E3; c1c1b3 }

.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 
.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}
.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}   

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}  
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}  

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;"}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;"}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 580; color: #ffffff; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}

.b2{border:2px solid #efefdc;}
.inp_sel{width: 80%;}


.form-bg {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:1080px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.data-bar {
  border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;

}

.column1 {     margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 450px;     border:0;     float: left; } 
.column2 {     color:black; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 50px;     float: right; }

.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}

.data-box-nat {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb;
margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.data-box-pct {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb; 
}
.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb; 
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.data-box-country {
width:650px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb; 
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#table td { 
margin:120px; 
} 

.personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  
.otherDetails {     float:right;     width:300px;      }

a img     { border: 0;}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what is your screen/browser resolution?

Comment: You can try with a table based layout, it's probably more easy for you to control the output and it does work well with older browsers as well.

Comment: Can you change the html or do you need to keep this exact html?

Comment: @easwee I can change the HTML. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Without reading your code at all, it looks like the parent element of those 3 inputs is restricting the space that they are in, which makes them retreat to as many rows as they need to. To avoid stuff like this, you may for example give the parent element a static width ( Width that will hold all of them in one row. ) Firebug for the win!

Comment: Please, don't ever create a table based layout. The `display: table;` attributes in css can be handy sometimes, but don't ever use html tables to create a layout. That hasn't been necessary for many years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urs code itself works pretty well... Three radio buttons comes in same line in firefox and chrome.. but i dont know about IE ...[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya/UTNPz/)